# Batch files to combine multiple files (that have parentheses in their names)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

The background: I'm using IFTTT to pull DC Metro bulletins from their RSS feed into a text file for my BBS. The biggest problem is that IFTTT cannot overwrite or append to files, so I get multiple copies of files in the directory:

```
red.txt
red (1).txt
red (2).txt
```

and so on.
I'm leaving the original (non-`(x).txt`) version of the file as a place holder and concentrating on merging the other files throughout the day.
For one set of files this works:

```
if exist "red (1).txt" for %%f in ("red (*.txt") do type "%%f" >> red_line.txt & del "%%f"
```

Since there are multiple sets of files (each a different color or combination of colors), I'm trying to create a parent `for`/`do` loop to cycle through the different Metro lines (to make the code easier to maintain). I could always just add a new instance of the above for each of the Metro lines.

I think the parentheses in the file names are interfering with the parentheses in the loop, because it immediately breaks. There must be a way to escape the parentheses, but I've tried slashes and carets, etc.; nothing seems to work. I'm hoping there's a better way to do this.

This is the base of the code, without the myriad of things that I've tried already:

```
FOR %%A IN (red green orange red_orange) DO  ( 
if exist "%%A (1).txt" for %%B in ("%%A (*.txt") do type "%%B" >> %%A_line.txt & del "%%B"
)
```

This is an example of what I get:

```
C:\sbbs\Dropbox\bbs\ifttt>(if exist "red (1).txt" for %B in ("red (*.txt") do type "%B" 1>>red_line.txt & del "%B" )

C:\sbbs\Dropbox\bbs\ifttt>(if exist "green (1).txt" for %B in ("green (*.txt") do type "%B" 1>>green_line.txt & del "%B" )

C:\sbbs\Dropbox\bbs\ifttt>(if exist "orange (1).txt" for %B in ("orange (*.txt") do type "%B" 1>>orange_line.txt & del "%B" )

C:\sbbs\Dropbox\bbs\ifttt>(if exist "yellow (1).txt" for %B in ("red_orange (*.txt") do type "%B" 1>>red_orange_line.txt & del "%B" )
```

This the part of the result that I'm seeing is borked:

```
 do type "%B" 1>>
```

That "1" must be from the (1), right?

I also notice that my spaces are not carried over into the results:

```
do type "%B" 1>>orange_line.txt
```

Comment: The closing parenthesis will cause problems, use a circumflex to escape it in a batch file: ^) Alternatively, you could loop over all files, e.g. red*.txt, and then check if the full name is NOT equal to red.txt.

Comment: A quick answer to part of your question: The Windows Command Prompt, like `bash` and most (if not all) other Unix shells, lets you say `2>`, `3>`, etc., to redirect file descriptors other than 1 (standard output). If you say `>` or `>>` in a batch file, and then run it with echo on, it will output as `1>` or `1>>`, just to show you what file descriptor it’s writing to. Also, if you put `echo foo > foo.txt` in a batch file, it will display as `echo foo 1>foo.txt` (the space after the `>` disappears). So, neither of those symptoms are actual problems.

Comment: if you are already using IFTTT, look at renaming the file to a timestamped name once it appears, with a second workflow.

Comment: Consider using Perl instead of bash with the system("mv", $f1, $f2) syntax or even the rename() syntax, both of which should have no problems with parentheses in filenames.

Comment: No need for PERL if using Windows. Use PowerShell with the suggestion from Berend to us red*.txt etc.

Comment: I just tried your code (in a very limited, watered-down testbed) and it worked. Are you sure it’s not working for you? You do know that it’s normal for a for a batch file to display what it’s doing on the screen, right? You can stop that by putting `@echo off` at the beginning of the batch file. If you want to display some parts but not others, just put a `@` at the beginning of every command that you want _not_ to be displayed. If you want to see what’s going on, I suggest that you use `echo` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in PowerShell rather than CMD. In PowerShell create an outer loop for all of the folders, get the files from each folder as an array of file objects and then you don't care about the names.

Merge into a new file and delete the processed files - or move them to an archive if you might want them again.